# Page builder Plugin for html templates

Tags: html

I am developing html of admin panel from xd.In it there is a page builder plugin like gutenberg which is used in wordpress.can anyone suggest plugin like this for simple html templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Web Export" plugin in Adobe XD. You can export the HTML and CSS. Then use the HTML in WordPress.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i need similar plugin to use in html template not in wordpress